# Java tan function is not working as expected

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tan 45 gives me 0.9999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775550/tan-45-gives-me-0-9999)

When I use `tan` I get a long long answer:

```
double degrees = 45.0;
double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
System.out.println(Math.tan(radians));
```

When I run this code I get:

```
0.9999999999999 repeating
```

Why?

Comment: Why do you expect an exact answer from conversion to radians followed by tan? The conversion to radians can be off by half a ulp (unit least place), and the Math.tan calculation can be off by up to one ulp.

Answer (score 1):

Because doubles (or in fact the system underling doubles, IEEE754) isn't perfect.  Always be aware of this when working with doubles and floats (in any language, not just Java).

Answer (score 1):

why not? this is near to one. floating point operations are never exactly. 
The reason is that numbers in the CPU are represented in binary form.
and a binary föoating point representation cannot exactly reprsent e.g 1/10.

Just read a bit about floating point programming.